# ¿Cómo validar con regex para aceptar solo letras, espacio o vacío?

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un campo de texto y quiero validar el valor para que sólo admita letras, espacios en blancos, o vacío. Hasta el momento lo único que tengo es esto:

```
/^[\pL\s]+$/u
```

Pero al dejar el campo en blanco, igual me da formato inválido. ¿Por qué puede estar pasando? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3):

Varios puntos que ver en tu expresión regular:

```
/^[\pL\s]+$/u
```

- **/^** Significa que validará desde el inicio de la cadena ingresada.
- **[ ]** Buscará hacer match con lo que hay dentro de los corchetes.
- **\pL** Buscará hacer match con letras de cualquier lenguaje, también podrías escribir **a-zA-ZáéíóúüñÑ** si sólo buscas letras del español, como está te aceptará letras como *ë* o *Ç*.
- **\s** Buscará hacer match con *espacios en blanco*, es decir espacio, tabulador, retorno de carro, nueva linea, también podrías escribir **\t\r\n\f**.
- **+** Buscará hacer match una o varias veces lo que haya a la izquierda.
- **$/u** Significa que validará hasta el fin de la cadena ingresada ingresando el modificador u que es el encargado de hacer validación de caracteres usando unicode.

En tu expresión regular te falta considerar el caso de cadena vacía, por que el signo de **+** hace match con "**uno o más** de los caracteres a la izquierda", y lo que necesitas es validar "**nada o más** de los caracteres a la izquierda", para eso puedes usar el signo de * (**asterisco**), entonces tu expresión regular quedaría así:

```
/^[\pL\s]*$/u
```

Entonces la definición que te falta analizar es:

- **[ ]*** Buscará hacer match ninguna o varias veces lo que haya entre los corchetes.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar este regex:

```
/^[A-Za-zñÑ\s]*$/
```

o éste, incluyendo acentos:

```
/^[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ\s]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Jorge:

Podrías utilizar:

`[a-zA-Z\t\h]+|(^$)`

Donde \s te valida:

`\n`: Saltos de línea.

`\t`: Tabulaciones.

`\v`: Espacios en vertical.

Y otros formatos tomado como cualquier carácter con espacio en blanco.

`|` : Sería un or, para evaluar una condición u otra.

`^$` : Filtraría una empty string o cualquier campo en blanco.

Podrías en lugar de `\s`, utilizar `\t\h` si quieres tabulaciones y espacios en blanco solamente.

`[a-zA-Z\t\h]+|(^$)`

Luego podrías utilizar preg_match con la expresión regular y lo que deseas filtrar de la siguiente forma:

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z\t\h]+|(^$)/', $datosQueNecesitasFiltrar)
```

Comment: Coincide con `"aa.!*@#$"`, algo que creo que no debería pasar como válido

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. ¿Podrías explicarnos cómo se hace en lugar de solo comentar en cada una de los distintas respuestas que no es correcto?

Comment: Ya está bien respondida, podés leer la respuesta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/365727/193460... Eso no quita que pueda comentarte sobre un error en tu respuesta

Comment: En ningún momento dije que o no puedas comentar, por supuesto que puedes 

Answer (score 0):

No es exactamente como lo estás pidiendo, pero lo pongo como una opción complementaria. Una opción *no regex* podría ser usando las funciones [ctype_*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.ctype.php)

```
<?php
function check_str($str) {
    $str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
    if((strlen($str) == 0) or ctype_alpha($str)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Pruebas:

```
var_dump(check_str("")); // true
var_dump(check_str("Hola Mundo")); //true
var_dump(check_str("Hola Mundo 3")); // false
var_dump(check_str("Hola \t Mundo")); // false
```

Si quisieras permitir más caracteres entonces esta variable habría que cambiarla a:

```
$str = str_replace(array(' ', '.', "\n"), '', $str); // Por ejemplo
```

Comment: Habla de "espacios en blanco" (no sólo espacios) y usa `\s` que coincide con cualquiera de los siguientes `"\n\r\t\f\v "`. Es buena respuesta pero creo que faltaría incluir esos

Answer (score -1):

probá con esta:

```
/(^$)|[a-zA-Z]/
```

Comment: Hola, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles: ¿qué hace ese regex? ¿cómo funcionaría? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: ... además coincide con `"aa.!*@#$"`, algo que no debería pasar como válido